# regex match group (select any character and number into one group)

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

How to capture any alphabet and any numeric into one group using regex. 
I use basic regex to capture it, but every single character become a new match.
According to image below, I want the result like this:

```
match 1 = Q
match 2 = m
match 3 = C
match 4 = t2
match 5 = result (this word 'result' just an example, it can be replaced by any word)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to match any word? `\w+`?

Comment: Why do you not want to match `c` ? Is it because its between two `*` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew basically I want any match that close to another match will join to a new match, not become two or more separated matches.

Comment: What is the exact rule for matching? Match 1+ walphanumeric chars that..... Please complete

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Sorry, I want to match c too. I'll update it. I also use any other character like *, +, -, /, ^, [, ]. That's why I'm using \w and \n to capture that I think more simple. It's not a must anyway.

Comment: Read a tutorial about regex to learn the basics, you will waste less time.

Comment: Sure, I'll read it :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How this question is a duplicate? All the answers of previous questions are very different with this question's answer. Not just the answer, the question itself is not same with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `+` for *one or more*

```
/[[:alnum:]]+/
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8xNHjG/1)

Be aware that `\n` matches a newline and not a number. `\d` would be the [short](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html) for *digit*.
`\w` (word character) matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. It includes `\d` already .

Comment: Thanks! You save my time.

Comment: you're welcome @Kevin